# disable browser location prompt

Tags: html, geolocation, browser

okay so i have been playing with the *html5* *geolocation* tonight, and i was wondering is there a way to disable a browser from prompting a user from selecting wether they may/ or may not want to allow my site to track them? Because i need to track them to get there accurate time zone, and things like that but if a user was to deny the site from locating them, i would have now timezone, state, city, zip, etc..... I guess what im looking for more of a hack!!!
jQuery code:

```
  jQuery("#btnInit").click(initiate_watchlocation);  
  jQuery("#btnStop").click(stop_watchlocation); 

  var watchProcess = null; 

  function handle_errors(error)  
        {  
            switch(error.code)  
            {  
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("Yo");  
                break;  

                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("could not detect current position");  
                break;  

                case error.TIMEOUT: alert("");  
                break;  

                default: alert("unknown error");  
                break;  
            }  
        } 

function initiate_watchlocation() {  
    if (watchProcess == null) {  
        watchProcess = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(handle_geolocation_query, handle_errors);  
    }  
}  

function stop_watchlocation() {  
    if (watchProcess != null)  
    {  
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchProcess);  
        watchProcess = null;  
    }  
}

function handle_geolocation_query(position) {  
    var text = "Latitude: "  + position.coords.latitude  + "<br/>" +  
               "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude + "<br/>" +  
               "Accuracy: "  + position.coords.accuracy  + "m<br/>" +  
               "Time: " + new Date(position.timestamp);  
                jQuery("results").html(text);  

}
```

Answer (score 6):

**You can't.**

The W3C wrote about security and privacy considerations of Geolocation API in the [document](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#security). Every browser which implemented Geolocation API must have followed this rule. This is native feature so there's no hack to avoid it.

Comment: More specifically, if you find a way to circumvent the permission prompt, you've found a security hole, and the vendor will patch it with high priority.